# Can I edit the motion path?

Tags: path

Can I change the motion path only by editing the line in the motion path?
I want to change the path by editing the line created by the motion path

[image]

Instead of following the white line I want my bone to follow the red one

Comment: you mean change the curve that is used in a Follow Path constraint? of course you can

Comment: how can I do that?
I did not use follow path constraint for each part of my bones?

Comment: please be more specific, what motion path are you talking about? give screenshots and perhaps share your file if necessary: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, you can not interact with the Motion Path (the white dotted line with yellow keyframe indicators). It is merely a visual **reference**.

You can edit the motion of the object ...

1. by [setting additional keyframes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/editing.html#insert-keyframes).
2. by changing the keyframe interpolation or bezier types in the [dopesheet](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/dope_sheet/introduction.html)
3. by changing the F-Curves of the animated channels in the [graph editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/index.html)
4. by animating it along a path with a *[Follow Path Constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html)*

---

Editability of the motion path may be achieved through the addon **Motion Trail Addon**:

- [Blender Addon List](http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.com/2013/10/addon-motion-trail.html)
- [BlenderArtist post](https://blenderartists.org/t/motion-trail/632918)

[image: motion path adon]
<sup>Motion Path Addon (gif)</sup>

Comment: The add-on in the answer is broken for 2.8+. This seems like a huge omission from the program, it's a really basic function.